# How to update fields in MongoDB applying function to existing value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

In MongoDB 3.6, I have a collection of documents like this:

```json
[
  {
    ...
    "propertyName": "[\"foo\",\"bar\"]",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Using Mongo shell, I want to update each document by executing JSON.parse() function on each propertyName value, so the documents will look like

```json
[
  {
    ...
    "propertyName": [
      "foo",
      "bar"
    ],
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

How can I do that? I don't know how to access existing value of the property and I cannot find any example that uses a function to update the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function (doc) {
   db.collection.updateOne(
      { _id: doc._id },
      { $set: { propertyName: JSON.parse(doc.propertyName) } }
   );
})
```